# ListView Custom Layout Error

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have `ListView` with custom layout. There are two `View's` in custom layout one is `TextView` other is `EditText` when i enter value in `EditText` and hide the keyboard my entered value disappear and value is restored to default.
How can i resolve it?

This is my layout

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your layout ?

Comment: Provide your issue with image. & share your code for better understanding of issues.

Comment: I have added my layout.

Comment: We need the actual code for workaround provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for resolve the issues.

Comment: The code is pretty much simple just one `ListView` and there is an adapter of that `ListView`.

Comment: Add your error with image so we can understand the issue.

Comment: share your code of adapter, specifically getView method